# How to reverse a string in AVR Assembly language

Tags: assembly, avr

So I have to strings in the cseg that look like this

```
msg1_p: .db "Potato", 0 
msg2_p: .db "Paramer", 0
```

I'm trying to write a subroutine that when called, reverse each string and stores the reversed string in `msg3_p` and   `msg4_p`respectively.

Here's the algorithm  I came up with:

```
reverse_string:

push msg1_p unto stack letter by letter

pop of msg1_p letter by letter and store in msg3_p

push msg2_p unto stack letter by letter

pop of msg2_p letter by letter and store in msg4_p

return form subroutine
```

The only problem is that I have no idea how to implement this assembly language.
I'd really appreciate some help on this. I'm using AVR studio 4 atmeg2560 avr simulator. Thank you

Comment: Surely the AVR Instruction Set Manual will shed some light on how to manipulate the stack?

Comment: @Michael i'm quite new to assembly and sadly I'm not tat good at it. Believe me when I said i've gone through the manual and countless other resources. No matter what I try, it doesn't work

Comment: What would be more productive than showing this pseudo code would be your attempts using actual 2560 mnemonics.

Answer (score 1):

So let's peek at what the GNU tools for AVR are implementing: Run

`> echo "" | avr-gcc -xc - -Wl,-u,strrev -o foo.elf -mmcu=avr4 && avr-objdump -d foo.elf`

This compiles an empty input file `-` as C-code (`-xc`) and sets symbol `strrev` to *undefined*, so the linker will drag it from libc. `strrev` reverses a string in-place.  Then dis-assemble the generated ELF file:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <strrev>:
   0:   dc 01           movw    r26, r24
   2:   fc 01           movw    r30, r24
   4:   67 2f           mov r22, r23
   6:   71 91           ld  r23, Z+
   8:   77 23           and r23, r23
   a:   e1 f7           brne    .-8         ; 0x4
   c:   32 97           sbiw    r30, 0x02
   e:   04 c0           rjmp    .+8         ; 0x18
  10:   7c 91           ld  r23, X
  12:   6d 93           st  X+, r22
  14:   70 83           st  Z, r23
  16:   62 91           ld  r22, -Z
  18:   ae 17           cp  r26, r30
  1a:   bf 07           cpc r27, r31
  1c:   c8 f3           brcs    .-14        ; 0x10
  1e:   08 95           ret
```

According to the [Calling Convention](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Calling_Convention), the address of the string is passed in R25:R24.

The 1st loop finds the rightmost character of the string, and the 2nd loop performs the actual reversal.

**What's left for you as todo**

- Use proper labels for legibility instead of jump offsets.
- Adjust to the ABI you are using.
- The code was compiled for arch `avr4` which supports `movw` and `sbiw`.  This might be different depending on the device you are using. For ATmega2560, the code is fine, though.
- If the reversal need not be in-place but to newly allocated memory, some modificatins are needed, which should be feasible given the starting point above.